# XSLT Preserve Order

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to preserve the order of the original nodes in a XSLT transformation, for example:

I have the following file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd1></cd1>
    <cd2></cd2>
    <cd2></cd2>
    <cd1></cd1>
</catalog>
```

This is my XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd1">
      <node>1</node>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd2">
      <node>2</node>
      </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <node>1</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>1</node>
</root>
```

But actually is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <node>1</node>
    <node>1</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>2</node>
</root>
```

Is there any way to preserve the order of the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `xsl:for-each` (which you should avoid whenever possible), write templates that match for the cd elements.

**The problem with your approach**

If you write your `for-each` like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd1">
```

you force XSLT to process any child nodes of `catalog` that are called "cd1" *first*. That is, it will only start to process the second `for-each` when all the `cd1` elements have been processed.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
  <root>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd1">
  <node>1</node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd2">
  <node>2</node>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <node>1</node>
  <node>2</node>
  <node>2</node>
  <node>1</node>
</root>
```

Comment: If he's limited to CD1 and CD2, I wouldn't suggest something like that if number of numbered child nodes is unknown...

Comment: Why not? What is your reservation with it?

Comment: That if he has a node cd3 then he has to add a new rule. The day after a cd4 will come out and he'll need to add another rule. Value may be just unknown (because that's just how an arbitrary application exports data) and...? He has to set a very high limit like cd99 to sleep sweet dreams?

Comment: That said I don't mean this is wrong! Templates are right solution, just I wouldn't write an example so restricted when it can be generic.

Comment: XSLT code depends heavily on the structure of the input. If the input requires dynamic templates, I'm happy to provide them. Otherwise - I don't think it's worthwile because the extra flexibility might never be of use.

Comment: But now that I think of it, actually it would have been easier to write a template like `match="*[starts-with(name(),'cd') and parent::catalog]"`. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Hi, in this case, the XSL will be autogenerated based on some restrictions with a graphical tool. All the cases will be wrote explicitly.

Comment: @JesúsGalindo: What do you mean?

Comment: In the case of Cd1..cd2....etc until cd99, is not possible, there is a graphical tool in development, where the user build the relations graphically (dragging a node from the origin xml and dropping in the destination xml), the program have to build the proper xsl file to implement that rules.

Comment: This is hardly feasible to implement. As far as I know, Altova supports translating trivial changes in XML to XSLT code. Beyond that, this is virtually impossible. Also, it seems that you've taken code from W3Schools.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to do that, for-each accepts several paths instead only one, for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd1 | catalog/cd2">
```

With that approach I got the desired output :)